# Why Activity getIntent().getExtras() will return null sometimes?

Tags: android

I have an Activity, where under rare situation, its `getIntent().getExtras()` will return `null`.

```
public class NewNoteChecklistLauncherFragmentActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String NEW_NOTE_CHECKLIST_LAUNCHER_FRAGMENT = "NEW_NOTE_CHECKLIST_LAUNCHER_FRAGMENT";

    private int mAppWidgetId = AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        this.mAppWidgetId = getIntent().getIntExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);

        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        NewNoteChecklistLauncherFragment newNoteChecklistLauncherFragment = (NewNoteChecklistLauncherFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag(NEW_NOTE_CHECKLIST_LAUNCHER_FRAGMENT);

        if (newNoteChecklistLauncherFragment == null) {
            Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
            if (bundle == null) {
                // WHY?
                throw new java.lang.RuntimeException();
            }
```

---

I'm not really sure how that happen. As, every-time, I'm launching the `Activity` with call to `putExtra`

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, NewNoteChecklistLauncherFragmentActivity.class);
Note note = new Note();
i.putExtra(NewNoteChecklistLauncherFragment.INTENT_EXTRA_NOTE, note);
```

At the same time, it also act as intent filter for "share" action.

```
<activity android:name="com.yocto.wenote.note.NewNoteChecklistLauncherFragmentActivity"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
    </intent-filter>

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
    </intent-filter>

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

I'm not able to produce such problem. But, once a while, I can see such thing happens in production.

Any idea, in what situation, `getIntent().getExtras()` will return `null` for the above case?

Comment: Is this activity exported? Can some tinkerer perhaps be starting the activity themselves, whether from another app or `adb`?

Comment: Oh yes. I forget to mention, It also act as `<action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />`. Can that be a reason? But, when I share from external app, there are no crash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be a buggy `ACTION_SEND` implementation that failed to attach any extras. This could be some automated script — or script kiddie — manually invoking your activity without any extras.

Since the activity is exported, I recommend some "defensive programming". Do not assume the existence of an extras `Bundle`. Instead, "gracefully degrade" as best you can in that case.

Comment: Fair enough. I will then call `this.finish()` if the bundle is null.